# analog milliseconds for clock in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I am actually trying to make an analog stopwatch app for iOS.Does anybody know what will be the right approach to have an analog clock with milliseconds hand. My problem is that the core graphics of iOS SDK does not support that high a refresh rate to refresh the movement of the milliseconds hand. Can anybody help with OpenGL-ES since I have a very little experience with OpenGL, so just need some tips for a head start.

Comment: So the hand goes round the face 1000 times a second?  Who could see that anyway?

Comment: tag hueur has a wrist wawtch called flying mikrotimer 1000, search on youtube and you should find the video that will amaze you with the real physical analog stopwatch...that was my inspiration... even though you can just see a ghost clock hand revolving around, it looks fantastic when it starts and stops at your single touch...

Comment: AFAIK it's impossible to get more than 60 fps on an iOS device. The system limits rendering to that rate.

Comment: @trojanfoe: the hand makes a full revolution in 1/10th of a second but the dial goes from 0 to 100.

Comment: @JeremyP thanks for clarifying, and sorry trojanfoe, i guess i'd messed up the question. anyways thanks for looking in to the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know you won't get the same result of your TAG Heuer watch (because of the refresh rates), you should interpolate the time to your needs.

To make things easier, I'll try to demonstrate a pointer that makes one lap each second.

- Step 1: Get the elapsed time (assuming each unit is 1/100 second). Example value: 234 (wich is 2.34 seconds, in our scale).
- Step 2: Reduce it to the elapsed time within your timeframe. (if you're measuring 1/100 second, you already used 200 for 2 full laps, you only need the ramaining of that). In our case: 34. How to obtain? In C: `234 % 100 = 34`.
- Step 3: Rotate your coordinates accordingly: in pure OpenGL: [glRotatef](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml)`(((float)34/100)*360, 0, 1, 0);` (This is rotating around the Y axis. The OpenGL uses degrees, so, a full circle = 360).
- Step 4: Draw your pointer
- Step 5: Start over (since you're retrieving the time again in step 1, you'll redraw your pointer on the new location).

Remember that this is just the "drawing" phase and Step 5 is just a consequence of your running loop and is illustrated just for clarification.

Hope it helps get you started. If you need more specifics, just comment on the answer and I'll try to help you out!